# SED - what is the diff between 1) and 2) - why no match in 2)

Tags: sed

1. ```
   echo "123456xx111"| sed '{s/\([x]\)/{\1}/}'
   123456{x}x111
   ```
2. ```
   echo "123456xx111"| sed '{s/\([x]+\)/{\1}/}'
   123456xx111
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905)

Comment: Is there a question?  Those outputs look correct to me (though I believe you're relying on a GNU extension with those unseparated `{` and `}` commands).

Answer (score 4):

Plus needs a backslash if supported at all (it's a GNU extension):

```
echo "123456xx111"| sed '{s/\([x]\+\)/{\1}/}'
123456{xx}111
```

Or, switch to extended regular expressions:

```
echo "123456xx111"| sed -E '{s/([x]+)/{\1}/}'
123456{xx}111
```

You can simplify your expression a lot, as the outer `{}` don't do anything (and may not work in some sed implementations without a semicolon or newline before the closing brace); a one element character class is equivalent to the character itself; and when replacing the whole string, you don't have to capture anything:

```
echo "123456xx111"| sed -E 's/x+/{&}/'
123456{xx}111
```

or, without `-E`, without any GNU extensions (so using the quantifier `\{1,\}` "one or more"):

```
echo "123456xx111"| sed 's/x\{1,\}/{&}/'
123456{xx}111
```